# Error code meanings?

Tags: discussion, error-message

Is it a good idea to ask only the detailed meaning of an error code? Without caring about the problem or solution to it, just what the error code actually means.

Example: ["Could not parse PKey: no start line"](http://google.com/search?q=Could+not+parse+PKey:+no+start+line)

Error codes like these could arise in more than one completely different situations. It could be useful to understand what it actually means, instead of having answers to fix one particular problem it occurs in.

Answer (score 2):

I think generally, we want to know about how the error code was obtained. Errors don't happen without a reason, and most of the time the *context of the error* is just as important as the error message itself.

I understand there may be special cases, but my gut instinct would be that if someone just posted "Can someone tell me what this error means?" with just the error message and no code or procedure to explain the story, I would flag the question as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this would be acceptable unless you indicate how you're getting the error.

You're correct that *error codes like these could arise in more than one completely different situations*, but you're asking for a list of things that might cause the error.

Questions asking "What does this thing mean?" without specifics is basically asking for a list of possibilities, and therefore it's speculative. You could get a whole litany of individual answers.

> It means 'this' when you do 'that'
>
> It means 'this other thing' when you do 'that other thing'.
>
> It can also mean 'this third thing' when you do 'yet a different thing'.

I'd vote to close this type of question as too broad.